# How to invoke an opened Exceed window to run a Perl script using a Schedule Task

Tags: perl, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

**TASK TO BE ACCOMPLISHED:**
To schedule a perl script which is executed on a specific time / day in a week

**THINGS I HAVE DONE:**
In a schedule Tasks, I have created a new Task by which the Task will call a batch file with below contents

***cd "DRIVE\FOLDER\Hummingbird\Connectivity\14.00\Exceed\"***

***ABCD.xs***

***cd mDrive/bin***

***perl baseline.pl -publish  -location XXX -email***

**THINGS NOT WORKING FOR ME / CAUSING THE ISSUE:**
Wen I run the scheduler, the prompt opens up the ABCD.xs exceed file window seperately file but the below commands are executed in the command pronpt itself

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**
I want the commands
***cd mDrive/bin
perl baseline.pl -publish  -location XXX -email***  
to be executed in the exceed window

Any kind of solution wud be great

Thanks in advance.

Haresh

Comment: I found out Exceed is an X server. For the benefit of us who are not familiar with the software, what happens when **ABCD.xs** runs? Does it spawn an xterm or perform some other sort of (pseudo) terminal activity? This information is crucial for giving an appropriate answer.

Comment: ABCD.xs opens up a CCM (Synergy) window (connecting to the server configured) which is all set expecting a command to execute...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to start getting into either SendKey stuff (Win32 packages) or else look into writing Exceed/Hummingbird scripts and just executing those.

Some other things to look into... does the remote server have a telnet or ssh server running?  Or are there other methods of executing code on the remote server?

For example, my work's mainframe is accessed via a Hummingbird terminal emulator, but I can also telnet to the mainframe and execute commands as well as FTP batch job directly into the JES spool.  So when I execute things on the mainframe by way of my PC (Perl scripts, etc.), I don't even fool with Hummingbird.

Good luck...